# Use a url from C++ in Qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to use QtCreator to create a UI that given a url in the C++ part of the code, it stores this url in a file and then pass it to the qml part of the code to diplay the site.
With the code that follows, I can run fine the program but I get only a white page:

**main.cc**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <qtwebengineglobal.h>

#include <QBluetoothLocalDevice>

#include "common/logging.hh"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QtWebEngine::initialize();

QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("qcp-ui");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationVersion(PROJECT_VERSION);
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("EDALab");
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("edalab.it");

QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);

common::initLogging();

qInfo() << "Started qcp-ui"
        << "version" << PROJECT_VERSION;

qInfo() << "Creating user interface context...";

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, [](QObject *obj, QUrl Url) {
    if (obj != nullptr)
        qInfo() << "Created qml root object" << Url;
    else
        qCritical() << "Failed to create qml root object!";
QQmlEngine engine;
QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
context -> setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("googleUrl"), "www.google.com");

});

engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));

// Test bluetooth
const auto btDevices = QBluetoothLocalDevice::allDevices();
if (btDevices.empty())
    qWarning() << "No local bluetooth device found!";
for (const auto& device: btDevices)
    qDebug() << "Found device" << device.name() << device.address();

return QGuiApplication::exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

ApplicationWindow {
id: window
visible: true
title: qsTr("qpc-ui")

Component.onCompleted: {
    window.showFullScreen();
}

WebEngineView {
    id: webEngineView
    url: googleUrl;
    anchors.fill: parent
}
}
```

For now I know I'm not storing the url in a file, I'm just trying to pass the url directly to the qml code but I can't understand where is the error.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;                                                                                   
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, [](QObject *obj, QUrl Url) {                   
  if (obj != nullptr)                                                                                           
    qInfo() << "Created qml root object" << Url;                                                                
  else                                                                                                          
    qCritical() << "Failed to create qml root object!";                                                         
});                                                                                                             
                                                                                                           
QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();                                                                    
context -> setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("googleUrl"), QStringLiteral("https://www.google.com"));
```

You want to set the context property outside of the lambda as the context needs to be available before loading your main.qml.

Make sure you're using `https://` or `http://`, otherwise the url won't be resolved correctly.

---

**Full working code**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QtWebEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

  QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("qcp-ui");
  QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("EDALab");
  QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("edalab.it");

  QtWebEngine::initialize();
  QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, [](QObject *obj, QUrl Url) {
    if (obj != nullptr)
      qInfo() << "Created qml root object" << Url;
    else
      qCritical() << "Failed to create qml root object!";
  });

  QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
  context -> setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("googleUrl"), QStringLiteral("https://www.google.com"));

  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));

  return QGuiApplication::exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried to use this code but I still get a white page... I have tried almost every combination of commands.

Comment: @Furla94 do you have `QtWebEngine::initialize();` before you create the application object? As seen in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#initializing-web-engine

Comment: Yes I have it inside the main, like in documentation

Comment: @Furla94 the call needs to be before you create any application, that's important. Can you try and run this example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webengine-minimal-example.html to see if that works?

Comment: I put the code you posted here inside the main as last part, so it's after `QtWebEngine::initialize();` ... Btw the example runs fine and also if instead of `url: googleUrl` in QML I use `url: "https://www.google.com"` , the webpage is visualized correctly

Comment: @Furla94 Ah I think I saw it, you're creating a new context. `QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();` should work

Comment: Still white page :/ plus I get a warning: qrc:/qml/main.qml:18: ReferenceError: googleUrl is not defined ... I'm updating the main post to include the whole code, maybe there is an error in other parts.

Comment: @Furla94 remove the line `QQmlEngine engine;` you're having `QQmlApplicationEngine engine;` already which is correct

Comment: By removing it I get an error:  variable 'engine' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified

Comment: With the last change I have no more the error, but I'm still getting a white page

Comment: @Furla94 you removed the https / http from the url, which is needed for the url to be resolved

Comment: I already added it again before to test the new code, but nothing change

Comment: Thank you very much, now the code is working fine!

Comment: A further question: if I want to access to the value of googleUrl inside the c++ code, how can I do that?

Comment: @Furla94 there's no good short answer. You can of course put the value in a variable and pass that variable to the setContextProperty call, as well as to your functions / classes that require this information. If you have multiple of these it might be better to create a class subclassing QObject and using Q_PROPERTY for the values. Then you can simply access them within QML via the object and pass the object / pointer around in C++. Another way would be a singleton. In the end it comes down to what you want to achieve.